# Issue encrypting my Seagate drive with Disk Utility on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, partition

I'm unable to encrypt an external hard drive because the encryption option seems to be missing. Various answers pointed to doing something with the 'Partition' button, but that button is greyed out. To solve the greyed-out issue, evidently, I first need to click on the 'view' button, but I have no view button!

(Specifically, I don't see a view button on my screen and the partition tab is greyed out.)

[image]

Comment: What happens if you select the next item below what's highlighted under **External**. Does the **Mount** _button_ become available and if so will it mount if you click it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to do this if the disk is formatted as FAT, FAT32, or EXFAT. In order to encrypt the disk, it has to be HFS or APFS.

You will need to format the disk to HFS or APFS and then you can encrypt. When formatting, there should be an option to format as APFS Encrypted or macOS Extended Encrypted. You can select either one of those or you can encrypt after formatting.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

From your screen capture, your external drive has an MBR (Master Boot Record) partition map.  To encrypt it, it needs a GPT (GUUID Partition Table) partition scheme.  You can then format with the file system format of your choice.

Before encrypting the drive it *must* be erased first, so if it has data you want to keep, you need to temporarily copy it to another location then copy it back once you finish the erase and encryption process.

For full details, see [Encrypt and protect a storage device with a password in Disk Utility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/encrypt-protect-a-storage-device-password-dskutl35612/mac)